# Why does my php file download instead of execute on Windows Azure?

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, azure

I am trying to setup Wordpress in a subfolder (/blog) on my ASP.Net MVC app that is hosted on Windows Azure.  When I navigate to /blog/index.php, the file downloads instead of executing.

I have done the following:

- Downloaded Wordpress and copied into /blog in the root of my web app
- Deployed the web app to Azure
- Enabled PHP version 5.5 (also tried 5.4)

I've clicked Restart in the portal for the web app.

Still downloads the file instead of executing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: probably didn't enable php in the webserver, so the file's being served up as an unknown mime type. e.g. iis/apache haven't been told that .php files should be run through the php plugin.

Comment: But I have (third bullet point in my question) - unless there's something else you need to do in Azure to enable PHP?

Comment: I do not have experience with Azure, but typically yes there is additional work to configure your webserver to use php in the form of an extension.

Comment: Are you hosting your site in a VM or on an Azure Web App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out that we had a BlockViewHandler sitting in our web.config, which was blocking access to all file types (including .php).  This might be unusual, but I'm posting this in case it helps someone else.

The tag we had was:

```
<handlers>
 <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```

It is designed to prevent unauthorised/hacking access.

Answer (score 1):

YOU need to add a `Handler Mapping`

I am not familiar with Azure, but...

You should have a IIS control panel with a Handler Mappings icon.

Add a Mapping Handler:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I'd assumed Azure would have done that for me, but possibly not.  I shall have a play and report back.

Comment: The Server needs to be told what to do when it transmits a file to the Browser.  If there is not "handler" it defaults to "text/plain" Content-Type.  On a windows server they may expect you to use ASP rather than PHP and do not configure the server to use PHP by default.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running the site in an Azure Web App, verify that PHP is turned on: 
Go to the site in the portal -> Settings -> Application Settings -> PHP version

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/